# Reload data from Excel by end users in QlikView

Tags: excel, qlikview

I have a script like this:

```
INPUTFIELD Amount1,Amount2;
Fact:   
LOAD * INLINE [   
    Group,Sales,  
     A,345    
     B,12    
     C,45    
     D,56    
     E,79    
     F,12    
     g,12    
     h,12    
     h,4    
];   
Fact1:    
LOAD    
*,Sales as Amount1,'' as Amount2,    
RecNo() as ID    
Resident Fact;    
Store Fact Into Fact.qvx;
```

There is a reload button for end users. Now I want that when a user clicks on the "send to Excel" button on a table header, they can enter a new record in the Excel file and then click on "reload" to load the updated data into the table.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having the inline load, why not put that info in a spreadsheet at a network location that the users can save to.

Then if they export, update and save over the old file the relaod will have the updated data